# How do I display database contents onto c# textbox

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

**Background** I'm transferring values from a text file to an sqlite database. The values are stored in lists then transferred into the database (Below)

[image]

**What I want** Now I want to get the values from the database and output them to a textbox in the application. Basically the user should click a button saying " Show file" which should simply display all of the column values from the database into the c# textbox, in essence I simply recreate the database (in the textbox).

**The Problem:** *I simply don't know sqlite or sql syntax (new programmer).* I understand I'll have to run a query using select, but then how would I select all the columns and then show all of them in the text box?

**My Attempt so far:** (Might have some obvious mistakes)

```
 sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM abc";

 //Command object gives us a datareader object
 sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();

 private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // SQlite datareader allows us to run through the lines
    // while ( sqlite_datareader.Read())
    {

     // Below is my approach on trying to display all column values
     // textbox1.Text = sqlite_datareader["Seq", "Field "," Desc "," Len ", etc etc ]; 

    }

 }
```

}

**SideNote:**
As the contents of the database are huge, and the textbox size is limited, it would be great if I could get some horizontal and vertical scrollbars

Comment: Wouldn't a grid of some sort be a better place to show database contents?

Comment: Since you are new to programming, perhaps you should look into the difference between a text box and a textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use datagrid instead of textbox

//Con = Connection Object
//Create Command Object
string sql;
SqlDataAdapter da;
DataTable dt;
SqlCommand com = con.createCommand();

//abc = your table name
//Provide Statement to Command Object
sql = " SELECT * FROM abc";
//Create New Datatable to fill with data
dt = new DataTable();

//Create DataAdapter to fill data in DataTable via Adapter
da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
da.Fill(dt);

//gridView1 = Your GridView Name
gridView1.DataSource = dt;
gridView1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void FillMyTextbox( )
{
    // open your database connection
    var sqlLiteConnection = OpenYourConnection( );

    // create command
    using( var sqlLiteCommand = sqlLiteConnection.CreateCommand( ) )
    {
        sqlLiteCommand.CommandText = "select * from abc";

        // create the reader
        using( var sqlLiteReader = sqlLiteCommand.ExecuteReader( ) )
        {
            // a StringBuilder to store the contents of your table 
            var allRecords = new StringBuilder( );

            while( sqlLiteReader.Read( ) )
            {
                for( int i = 0; i < sqlLiteReader.FieldCount; i++ )
                {
                    // either adress the column via an index or its name
                    var columnContentAsString = sqlLiteReader[ i ].ToString( );
                    allRecords.Append( columnContentAsString );
                }
                allRecords.Append( Environment.NewLine );
            }

            textBox1.Text = allRecords.ToString( );
        }
    }

    // somehow close/dispose your connection
}
```

I hope this code will get you the idea of how to access your datatable.
The `using` statement will take care of the disposing of the reader and the command object.
I would recommend using a `DataGridView` to display your data instead of using a `TextBox` but maybe for a testing purpose its okay.